# insert into mdb from a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to insert into a Access database with MySQL data with multiple tables with the same names

The Problem: I'm not sure how the Connections should be made because I've just been connecting to only 1 database (MySQL) now I need to connect to a mdb (Access).
I've gotten to a point where I can use "UCanAccess" but its a little bare bones and I'm not sure if it will work.

```
 Class clazz = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Class clazz2 = Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

 Connection MySQL_con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
 Connection Acc_con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL2);

 //How can I connect to Access and MySQL?
 PreparedStatement pst = MySQL_con.prepareStatement(
 "INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.table1
   SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.table1
   WHERE DB1.table1.x='5';");
```

Comment: You need to select from mysql and insert into access, they are two separate operation that need to be done on the correct connection. Execute the select on `MySQL_con` and insert with `Acc_con`. `INSERT INTO [...] SELECT` is supported on the same connection, you can't do it across multiple connections with different databases.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Connector/J cannot write to an Access database and UCanAccess cannot read from a MySQL database so you won't be able to copy the data using a single statement as described in your question. Instead, you would read using the MySQL connection and write using the UCanAccess connection, something like this:

```java
try (
        Connection mysqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlConnUrl);
        Statement mysqlStmt = mysqlConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet mysqlRs = mysqlStmt.executeQuery(
                "SELECT client_id, last_name FROM client WHERE x = '5'");
        Connection ucanaccessConn = DriverManager.getConnection(ucanaccessConnUrl);
        PreparedStatement ucanaccessStmt = ucanaccessConn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO client (client_id, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    while (mysqlRs.next()) {
        ucanaccessStmt.setInt(1, mysqlRs.getInt(1));
        ucanaccessStmt.setString(2, mysqlRs.getString(2));
        ucanaccessStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```